# Dynamically populate array with Firebase Data Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, chart.js

I am using Vue.js with Chart.js in order to retrieve some data from Firebase and display it on a chart. 
This is my code:

```
import {Line} from 'vue-chartjs'

let Firebase = require('firebase');
//
let config = {
    apiKey: '****************************',
    authDomain: '****************************',
    databaseURL: '****************************',
    storageBucket: '****************************'
};

let firebaseApp = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
let db = firebaseApp.database();
let schools = db.ref('schools');

export default Line.extend({
    firebase: {
        schoolsArray: schools
    },
    data(){
        alert('data');
        return {
            names: []
        }
    },
    computed: {
        schoolNames: function () {
            for (let item of this.schoolsArray) {
                this.names.push(item.name);
            }
            alert('computed');
            return this.names
        }
    },

    mounted () {
        alert('mounted');
        this.renderChart({
            labels: this.names.toString(),
            datasets: [{
                label: 'School Reports', backgroundColor: '#dd4935',
                data: [10, 20, 50, 12, 34, 43, 45]
            }]
        }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: true})
    }
})
```

The problem is that the **names** array are always empty and the labels are not displayed. Here is how it looks:
[image]

I need to display the school names on the **x** axis!

On the picture below is the Vue.js debugger results: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.ref('school')` returns a 'firebase.database.Reference' object you have to retrieve the data from it. you could add this to your vue `mounted` lifecycle hook:

```
db.ref('school').once('value')
 .then((dataSnapshot) => {
   this.schoolsArray = dataSnapshot.val();
 });
```

you could also use the `.on` method which will automatically fire your callback each time when the data changes on the server. so make sure you remove that when the component is destroyed.
for documentation see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once

Comment: I have posted one more picture which shows that the names are retrieved but are not shown on the graph!

Comment: does it help if you invoke your `renderChart` method in the `.once` callback again?

Comment: yes I use this code into the methods lifecycle hook and call it inside mounted before the renderChart but still I can't see any labels o my chart